# Getting alert while trying to delete using jQuery Ajax delete

Tags: jquery, python

I am getting the following popup while trying to delete a value. I'm using jQuery Ajax to delete the value. Programming language I use is python2.7 and the framework is Django 1.3.2

My code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: window.location.pathname + id + '/data-centers/' + dc,
    contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
    data: {
        dc : dc,
    },
    success: function(){
        alert("success");
    }
    etc...
```

When I confirm to delete the value I'm getting the following popup from the JavaScript saying:

```
"This web page is being redirected to a new location. Would you like to resend  
 the form data you have typed to the new location?
```

And in the Ajax header I can see following (it's trying to redirect to other location, but don't know why):

```
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  251
Content-Type    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date    Tue, 27 Nov 2012 13:53:44 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Location    http://www.test.com/403/test-403.html
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Request Headers
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  12
Content-Type    application/html; charset=utf-8
```

This only happens when I try to use DELETE.

Comment: You are being redirected to a 403 (forbidden) page. I guess the solution is to authorize the http DELETE verb on your server/application/controller

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, i have find that may be some error occured due to path of ajax is not proper or ajax call html may have some redirect issue. So if the path is not proper then you can set with different type of varaible as follow

---

```
$(location).attr('href');
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pageurl = window.location;
});
```

---

```
var currentpageURL = window.location.href;
```

---

```
var currentpagepath = getAbsolutePagePath();

function getAbsolutePagePath() {
    var pageurl = window.location;
    var pathName = pageurl.pathname.substring(0, pageurl.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    return pageurl.href.substring(0, pageurl.href.length - ((pageurl.pathname + pageurl.search + pageurl.hash).length - pathName.length));
}
```

May this will help you